# Can't get my player to rotate back to 0,0,0 when respawning

Tags: c#

I am making a basketball game where you shoot then the ball is positioned back into your hands after a timer runs out and you are sent back to your default position to shoot again. I can't get the player to rotate back to 0,0,0 though. any advice would be greatly appreciated.(This is my first game and i'm kinda winging it so i'm sure the rest of my code that works is still horrible, its a learning experience so any constructive criticism is welcome.)

My code...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public Ball ball;
    public GameObject playerCamera;


    public float ballDistance = 2f;
    public float ballThrowingForce = 5f;
    public float powerTimer = 0f;

    public bool holdingBall = true;

    public Player player;

    public float resetTimer = 5f;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = false;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (holdingBall) {
            {
                ball.transform.position = playerCamera.transform.position + playerCamera.transform.forward * ballDistance;

            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {

                if (powerTimer == 10) {
                    powerTimer = 10;

                } else if (powerTimer < 10) {
                    powerTimer = powerTimer + Time.deltaTime;
                    ballThrowingForce = ballThrowingForce + 2 * powerTimer;


                }
            }

        }           


        if (holdingBall) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {

                holdingBall = false;
                ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = true;
                ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (playerCamera.transform.position + playerCamera.transform.forward * ballThrowingForce);

            }       

        }
        if (player.holdingBall == false) {
            resetTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (resetTimer <= 0) {

                player.transform.position = new Vector3 (-0.2427547f, 2.6f, -2.357f);
                // player roation to 0,0,0 here

                holdingBall = true;
                ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = false;
                powerTimer = 0;
                ballThrowingForce = 400;
                resetTimer = 5;

            }       
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return)) {
                resetTimer = 0;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity` should work.

Let's take a look at that :

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {

            if (powerTimer == 10) {
                powerTimer = 10;

            } else if (powerTimer < 10) {
                powerTimer = powerTimer + Time.deltaTime;
                ballThrowingForce = ballThrowingForce + 2 * powerTimer;


            }
        }
```

This part is absurd :

```
if (powerTimer == 10) {
    powerTimer = 10;
}
```

Should be `powerTimer >= 10`.

And after, you execute `powerTimer += Time.deltaTime` which seems good, but `ballThrowingForce += 2 * powerTimer` is not what you want i think. Here ballThrowingForce is growing exponentially with powerTimer. Should perhaps be `ballThrowingForce += 2 * Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: thanks that worked to to stop the timer at 10, i still need to tweak the power of the throw and all that just wanted to get it working first. For some reason player.transformer.rotation = Quaternion.identity doesn't work.

Comment: sorry its 'player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity', i made a typing error :(